# LOCAL and CONGEST model in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am currently trying to understand a mathematical paper about graph theoretic concepts. In the abstract as well as in the introduction and through out the paper the "CONGEST" and "LOCAL" model is mentioned. I would like to ask if there is a clear definition to these terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are models of communication in [distributed computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing).

**The LOCAL model**:
Every vertex can send $poly(n)$ bits of information to each of its neighbors, each round.

**The CONGEST model**:
Every vertex can send $\log(n)$ bits of information to each of its neighbors, each round.

In both cases, the algorithm complexity is measured in the number of rounds it performs.

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I only tagged the question with "graph-theory" and a "distributed-computation" tag doesn't exist would you recommend to add a different kind of tag to make it more accessible?

Comment: I guess you can add the tags algorithms and computational-complexity :)